# Is redismodules part of redis 4.0-rc2?

Tags: redis

Release notes of redis 4.0-rc2 say that the modules in redismodules are part of the download.

Tried running ML.FOREST . Says unknown command

Thanks
Sreeni

Answer (score 2):

Redis 4.0-rc2 indeed supports the new modules API.
That being said, it does not come pre-packed with any module.

If you want to use a specific module you will have to first load it through the LOAD command or in the more recommended approach, by adding its path to your  redis.conf in the following way:

```
loadmodule /path/to/mymodule.so
```

You picked a very cool module to start with - redis-ml. You can find it on https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redis-ml

Hope this was a useful answer.